# problem in UITable cell selection

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

hai , 
i have coded in UITableview in the method as follows.but when i touch the cell or row ,it wont
go to the next page(navigation did not work).have i to declare navigation conroller in other file.but i have coded app delegate in applicationdidfinishmethod for tab bar through dynamic.how can i link navigation?
the code:
  **UITableview;**(**TableViewController)**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        SubController *nextController = [[SubController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    [nextController release];
}
```

**appdelegation:**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    



         tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @" News";
    TableViewController *rtbfViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] 
         init];

    rtbfViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"News";
    InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] 
              initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    infoViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Info";
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray 
             arrayWithObjects:rtbfViewController,infoViewController,nil];
    tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];


        [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
         [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you don't have a `UINavigationController`, so `self.navigationController` in your `TableViewController` is nil (and thus messages sent to this property are ignored). You should modify your code in the app delegate as follows:

```
// [...] create tab bar view controller...

// create navigation controller with TableViewController instance as root view controller
TableViewController *rtbfViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
rtbfViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"News";
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rtbfViewController];

// [...] create other view controllers

// NOTE: add the navigation controller to the tab bar controller, rather than the TableViewController
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController,infoViewController,nil];
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

And don't forget to release your view controllers afterwards:

```
[rtbfViewController release];
[navController release];
[infoViewController release];
```